# MySql - get user rank by result

Tags: mysql, sql

Given this table structure:

> ID   |  USER  |  SCORE |SCORE_DATE

I want to create a query which result is the rank of a score - my routine will get a parameter of score and will return the rank.

Given this data:

> 1 | user1 | 1300 | 1/2/2014
>
> 2 | user2 | 3300 | 1/2/2014
>
> 3 | user3 | 4300 | 1/2/2014
>
> 4 | user4 | 650 | 1/2/2014
>
> 5 | user5 | 1700 | 1/2/2014

If the paramter passed is 4000, I want the result to be 2, if the result is 2000 the result should be 3, if the paramter is 500 the result should be 6 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` and `where`:

```
select count(*)+1
from table t
where score > SCORE_PARAMETER;
```